# Simple Imputer cannot impute by column

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, imputation

I have X_train that shapes (14599, 13), i'm trying to impute NaN with column's median but somehow it imputes with row resulting error because in a row there are date, and other than integer values. I already lookup if SimpleImputer has axis parameter but could not find that it exists. How to solve this?

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


plt.close('all')
avo_sales = pd.read_csv('avocados.csv')
avo_sales.rename(columns = {'4046':'small PLU sold',
                            '4225':'large PLU sold',
                            '4770':'xlarge PLU sold'},
                 inplace= True)
avo_sales.columns = avo_sales.columns.str.replace(' ','')

plt.scatter(avo_sales.Date,avo_sales.TotalBags)

x = np.array(avo_sales.drop(['TotalBags'],1))
y = np.array(avo_sales.TotalBags)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)

imp = SimpleImputer(strategy='median')
X_train = imp.fit_transform(X_train)
```

the output

```
ValueError: Cannot use median strategy with non-numeric data:
could not convert string to float: '12/31/2017'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try and drop the date column when imputating:

```
X_train = imp.fit_transform(X_train.drop('date_column', axis=1)
```

Change the name 'date_column' to the right name.

Otherwise maybe transform the column with date column from string to date object:

```
X_train['date_column'] = pd.to_datetime(X_train['date_column'])
```

But I am not sure if SimpleImputer can handle date type

Comment: This would not work here, as `X_train` and `X_test` are actually Numpy arrays (which do not have a `drop` method) and not pandas dataframes (which do).